# mysql: same select slow even if table does not change

Tags: mysql, performance

Table ads has about 0.5 mio rows.

Time to time I use

```
select sql_calc_found_rows * from `ads` 
where cat1<>24 and 
      curdate()<=expiry and 
      offl=0 
order by ads.date desc ,id desc 
limit 0,30
```

Every time it needs almost the same time - even if ads does not change. does mysql not notice this fact?? and speed up??? so when query comes again, time should almost be zero.

Comment: You can enable query_cache. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

**Query Cache**

- If the QC is configured, and
- If the table has not changed since the *identical* query was run, and
- If a few other subtle things are satisfied, then

The QC will very quickly deliver the saved resultset.  However, because of the restriction on the table not changed, Production systems rarely benefit from the QC.

**innodb_buffer_pool**

The first time a query is run, the data is probably sitting on disk.  So the query must fetch the data and put it into the buffer_pool to act on it.

The subsequent times the query is run, the data *may* still be in that cache.  If so, it will be faster.

**Indexes**

Proper indexing is your first line of defense for speeding up queries.  That particular query may benefit from one of the following.  (It is hard to tell which will be best; only one will be used.)

```
INDEX(date, id)
INDEX(offl, expiry)
INDEX(offl, cat1, expiry)
```